# Multimap guava values

Tags: java, indexing, guava, multimap

I have this scenario:

```
ID={1,2,3}
Title ={T1,T2,T3} 
Place ={P1,P2,P3}
```

I want to have this result:

```
ID: 1 , Title: T1, Place: P1
ID: 2 , Title: T2, Place: P2
ID: 3 , Title: T3, Place: P3
```

I used Multimap (Guava) to store the ID and title with their multiple values:

```
Multimap<String, String> MultiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

However, I couldn't so far get the desired result as described above. I used this code as a try:

```
   for (Entry<String, String> key : MultiMap.entries()) 
    {
      System.out.println("name : " + key.getKey() + " value : " + key.getValue());
    }
```

However, using this code the result I got is like this:

```
name : ID value: 1
name : ID value: 2
name : ID value: 3 
name : Title value: T1
name : Title value: T2
name : Title value: T3
name : Place value: P1
name : Place value: P2
name : Place value: P3
```

How to get the result as I described above using Multimap?

Comment: You probably want `Map<Integer, String>` where key (ID) maps to title, not `Multimap<String, String>`. Just store your data in the map and print it with `System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getKey() + " Title: " + entry.getValue());`.

Comment: this was not the question. In my question more than one value can be assigned to one id or whatever is, e.g., Title, place, etc can be assigned to ID1

Comment: Maybe you could create an object that holds both title and place (ex. IdData), and then use a map<String, IdData>? This doesn't necessarily solve your question but could be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you understand correctly what a Multimap is. A Multimap maps from one or more keys to multiple values, it's an n-to-m relation. What you seem to have is a relation from an ID to a Title, which is an n-to-1 relation. The right data structure for this is a Map, not a Multimap.

```
Map<Integer, String> titlesById = new TreeMap<>(); // keep map ordered by ID
titlesById.put(1, "T1");
titlesById.put(2, "T2");
titlesById.put(3, "T3");
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : titlesById.entrySet()){
  System.out.println("ID : " + entry.getKey() + " Title : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

This should produce the desired output.

Note: if you are likely to look up titles by ID from the Map, then you probably want to switch from TreeMap to HashMap, as HashMap has constant time lookup.

---

Update: apparently you do need a Multimap. Then change the above code to something like this:

```
Multimap<Integer, String> titlesById = TreeMultimap.create<>(); // keep map ordered by ID
titlesById.putAll(1, Arrays.asList("T1a", "T1b", "T1c"));
titlesById.putAll(2, Arrays.asList("T2a", "T2b"));
titlesById.put(3, "T3");
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : titlesById.entries()){
  System.out.println("ID : " + entry.getKey() + " Title : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Again: `TreeMultimap` sorts the Map by the key, `HashMultimap` has efficient lookup.

---

It gets more and more interesting, now you want to have 3 values connected to each other. In that case, you should use a [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) (3-dimensional Map). E.g.

```
Table<Integer, String, String> titlesAndPlacesById = TreeBasedTable.create();
titlesAndPlacesById.put(1, "T1", "P1");
titlesAndPlacesById.put(2, "T2", "P2");
titlesAndPlacesById.put(3, "T3", "P3");

for(Table.Cell<Integer, String, String> cell : titlesAndPlacesById.cellSet()){
  System.out.println("ID : " + cell.getColumnKey() + " Title : " + cell.getRowKey() + ", Place: " + cell.getValue());
}
```

---

But this is not a perfect match. If you want to map an ID to a title and place, then you probably want to have a custom object encapsulating title and place, and use that as the value in a plain old Map from integer to custom type.

```
public class TitleAndPlace{
    private final String title;
    private final String place;

    TitleAndPlace(String title, String place) {
        this.title = title;
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public String getPlace() { return place; }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        else if (o instanceof TitleAndPlace) {
            TitleAndPlace that = (TitleAndPlace) o;
            return Objects.equals(title, that.title)
                && Objects.equals(place, that.place);
        } else return false;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(title, place);
    }
}

Map<Integer, TitleAndPlace> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1, new TitleAndPlace("T1", "P1"));
map.put(2, new TitleAndPlace("T2", "P2"));

for(Map.Entry<Integer, TitleAndPlace> entry : map.entrySet()){
  System.out.println("ID : " + entry.getKey() + " Title : " + entry.getValue().getTitle() + ", Place: " + entry.getValue().getPlace());
}
```

Comment: this was not the question. In my question more than one value can be assigned to one id or whatever is, e.g., Title, place, etc can be assigned to ID1

Comment: @StaOver I see no evidence of that in your sample data. But look at my updated answer anyway.